# Does using `restrict` when initializing a new pointer actually do anything?

Tags: c, pointers

I have been reading about the `restrict` keyword and every example I've seen uses it when defining a function.

```
void foo (int *restrict bar, float *restrict baz);
```

I have been reading through articles on it and wondering if this would be something valid.

```c
int main()
{
    int *restrict bar = malloc(sizeof(int));
    //... code using bar
    return 0;
}
```

I tested it with gcc and I am not receiving any compiler warnings, but will it actually *do* anything? Will the compiler pick up that this pointer for it's life will not overlap and that it will not be shared by any other pointer or will it only work when used when defining a function?

Comment: `restrict` doesn't make sense in the context of your example.

Comment: Ok, well that basically answers my question then. In it's location the compiler will not recognize that for the life of bar in int main, that it is restricted.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I think it requires explanation. I am not convinced :)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict#Block_scope. It has a very few legitimate uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The restricted 'bar' in main tell the compiler that the data will not be referenced via any other pointer. Depending on what main does, it might help with optimization of 'main'. If the only manipulation of `bar` is in function `foo`, there is no need to make it `restrict`.

As a side note, on Linux/gcc, the 'malloc' is tagged with `__attribute__ ((__malloc__))`, which tells the compiler that the returned value is restrict pointer, which will allow the compiler the perform the required optimization, if relevant. See: [understanding malloc.h difference: __attribute_malloc__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822553/understanding-malloc-h-difference-attribute-malloc) https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html

malloc

> ```
> This tells the compiler that a function is malloc-like, i.e., that the pointer P 
> returned by the function cannot alias any other pointer valid when the function
> returns, and moreover no pointers to valid objects occur in any storage addressed by P.
>
> Using this attribute can improve optimization. Compiler predicts that
> a function with the attribute returns non-null in most cases.
> Functions like malloc and calloc have this property because they
> return a pointer to uninitialized or zeroed-out storage. However,
> functions like realloc do not have this property, as they can return a
> pointer to storage containing pointers.
> ```